# The differences between variables of class type and objects of the class

Tags: java, c#-4.0

NEED info regarding languages JAVA and C#

**Q#1;- Class types vs Object types vs Reference types ?**

**Q#2:- Difference memory requirements for variables of class types and

      primitive types ?**

**Q#3:- difference between the scope of object of class and variable of class ?**

******* Please do correct me if the info below is incorrect **********

******* Please explain with the help of an example *******************

******* Will really appreciate the help ******************************

> ***PersonClass var1 = new PersonClass("Jack", 22);***

**PersonClass var1**:-  defines var of type class PersonClass "var1"

**new**:- "NEW" will allocate memory as per informed by constructor of class PersonClass

**PersonClass("Jack", 22);** :- "Constructor" which will tell the new operator about the size of the class and will be 1st thing which the complier will 
call when the prog runs

**1-** this will create an object of the class PersonClass with the help of new 
   operator

**2-** the constructor of the class PersonClass() will tell the new 
   operator about the size of the class and the new operator will 
   allocate the exact memory size.

**3-** the name of the object is "var1" and it is also the name of variable of Class type PersonClass

**4-** object of the class can access all the properties fields methods of 
   class except the private ones.

**5-** in case of a parametized constructor does the complier call the default constructor. who tells about the size of the class if there is no default constructor ?

> **PersonClass var2;**

**1-** it defines only the variable of class  "var2"

**2-**  what can a var2 of the class can access from PersonClass ?
    what is the limit of var2?
    what is the difference or scope of the var2 of class type 
    PersonClass and object of class PersonClass?

**

> var2 = var1;

**

// Both variable2 and variable1 now both name the same object
// please explain

/*this also changes variable1, since variable 2 and variable1
   name the same exact object */

variable2.set("Jack", 22);

System.out.println(variable1);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into the stack and heap.
here is video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clOUdVDDzIM) which explains the stack and heap. Seeing what kind of questions you have this will explain about 90% of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot ziraak it really helped